# Edittext give empty string when tab the space bar

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application i have one edittext which is used to add task in db.First i check it out the task if the task is empty means not add in db.My problem is when i tab the space bar in edit text and then add task in db the if condition is true  and it will stored the database with empty string.how to solve this problem thanks

```
final String task =editboxTask.getText().toString();
if (!task.isEmpty()) 
   {
     //add task in database
   }
```

Comment: Is it a typo that you assign the text of your EditText to the variable **task** but in your condition you refer to **checkTask**?!

Comment: oh sorry i edit my question please see that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String.trim()`, which removes heading and trailing whitespace from your string:

```
if(!task.trim().isEmpty()) ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Check object values in debug mode. And try to use `editboxTask.getText()` only.

Answer (score 0):

You should improve your condition by adding `task.isEmpty()` (please see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty()).

So it would look like:

```
   if (!task.isEmpty() && !task.equals(" ")) 
   {
     //add task in database
   }
```

Comment: Your updated post and my suggestion are still different. :) Just from the code you posted and when you change the condition to what I've mentioned above there should nothing be stored in the DB when: 1. the string is empty or 2. it only contains whitespace.

What exactly do you mean with duplicate? If you would like to avoid the insertion of duplicate values you may want to use the "unique" modifier for your DB scheme (please see http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html)